# Cannot build Maven Project

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have this maven configuration which I want to use on different operating systems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dx57dc</groupId>
    <artifactId>DX57DC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DX57DC</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.dx57dc.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>Windows XP</name>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                    <version>5.1.2600</version>
                </os>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                                    <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                        <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                        <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                        <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                        <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                        <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                        <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>  
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>

        <profile>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>Linux</name>
                    <family>Linux</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                    <!-- <version>5.1.2600</version> -->
                </os>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                                    <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                        <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                        <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                        <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                        <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                        <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                        <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                        <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>  
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <compilerArguments>
                                <bootclasspath>/opt/java/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                            </compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

I get this warning message:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ DX57DC ---
Error: Unable to access jarfile D:\Documents
```

Can you tell me what is the proper way to configure this POM file?

P.S After I added "" with them or without I get this error on Windows:

```
[exec:exec]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 more
Exception in thread "main" [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.000s
Finished at: Fri Aug 02 14:09:35 PDT 2013
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project DX57DC: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 4):

I think its because some of the arguments sent to exec-maven-plugin contains spaces.

In your case it looks like `${project.build.directory}` or some other variable resolves to `C:\Documents and Settings\something`.

When you are passing this:

```
<argument>-srcdir</argument>
<argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
```

It will resolve to: `-srcdir=C:\Documents and Settings\something/classes`.

When it should have been something like: `-srcdir="C:\Documents and Settings\something/classes"` with "".

Comment: I use NetBeans 7.4 in Windows XP. I put quotes in nbactions.xml: <exec.args>-jar "${basedir}/target/mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"</exec.args>. The problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In your exec-plugin configuration, put "" around all your properties `<argument>` tags (the ones that contain $ in them)
like this

```
<arguments>
     <argument>-createjar</argument>
     <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
     <argument>-appclass</argument>
     <argument>"${mainClass}"</argument>
     ....
</arguments>
```

Comment: looks like you're missing a jar in your classpath when you run maven-exec. One of your `<argument>` arguments is probably wrong, especifically the one containing javafx.application.Application. Either you are not passing its jar, or the class is not in the folder you think, check your properties paths to make sure the class is in one of them